# Laravel Form Request : bad method be called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, postman

When I use a Form Request with a Post method the response is the "`index()`" method response. But it's have to be the "`store(myRequest $request)`" method.
If I remove myRequest $request method from "`store()`" it's works. I'm lost.Please help me.

My controller :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Ressource;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateCollectionRequest;
use App\Repositories\CollectionRepository;

class CollectionController extends RessourceController {

    private $collectionRepository;

    public function __construct(CollectionRepository $collectionRepository)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->collectionRepository = $collectionRepository;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->run( function()
        {
            return $this->collectionRepository->all()->get();
        });
    }

    public function store(CreateCollectionRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->run( function() use ($request) {
        return $this->collectionRepository->create($request->all());
        });
    }
}
```

RessourceController :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Ressource;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

abstract class RessourceController extends Controller
{
    protected $result = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->result = new \stdClass();
        $this->result->error = 0;
        $this->result->message = '';
        $this->result->service = $this->getService();
        $this->result->data = null;
    }

    abstract public function getService();

    protected function render()
    {
        return Response::json($this->result);
    }

    public function missingMethod($parameters = [])
    {
        $this->result->err = 404;
        $this->result->message = 'Service ' . $this->getService() . ' : ' . $parameters . ' non disponible';
        return $this->render();
    }

    protected function run($function)
    {
        try {
            $this->result->data = call_user_func($function);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->result->err = ($e->getCode() > 0) ? $e->getCode() : -1;
            $this->result->message = $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->render();
    }
}
```

Custom Form Request :

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateCollectionRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'label' => 'required|alpha_num|min:3|max:32',
            'description' => 'alpha_dash|max:65000',
            'parent_collection_id' => 'exists:collections,id'
        ];
    }
}
```

Extract from routes.php :

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'Ressource', 'prefix' => 'ressource'), function () {
    Route::resource('collection', 'CollectionController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy']]);
});
```

Postman request :
[image: Postman request]

Postman reponse :

[image: Postman reponse]

Answer (score 0):

You should make your function become Clouse function. 
My controller :

```
use App\Http\Requests\CreateCollectionRequest;
use App\Repositories\CollectionRepository;
use SuperClosure\Serializer;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Closure;

class CollectionController extends RessourceController {

private $collectionRepository;

public function __construct(CollectionRepository $collectionRepository)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->collectionRepository = $collectionRepository;
}

public function index()
{
    return $this->run( function()
    {
        return $this->collectionRepository->all()->get();
    });
}
protected function buildCallable($callback) {
 if (! $callback instanceof Closure) {
    return $callback;
 }
 return (new Serializer)->serialize($callback);
}
public function store(CreateCollectionRequest $request)
{
    $callback = function() use ($request) {
      return $this->collectionRepository->create($request->all());
    }
    return $this->run($this->buildCallable($callback));
}
```

}

RessourceController :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Ressource;

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use SuperClosure\Serializer;
 use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 use Closure;

abstract class RessourceController extends Controller
{
protected $result = null;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->result = new \stdClass();
    $this->result->error = 0;
    $this->result->message = '';
    $this->result->service = $this->getService();
    $this->result->data = null;
}

abstract public function getService();

protected function render()
{
    return Response::json($this->result);
}

public function missingMethod($parameters = [])
{
    $this->result->err = 404;
    $this->result->message = 'Service ' . $this->getService() . ' : ' . $parameters . ' non disponible';
    return $this->render();
}
protected function getCallable($callback)
{
    if (Str::contains($callback, 'SerializableClosure')) {
        return unserialize($callback)->getClosure();
    }

    return $callback;
}
protected function run($function)
{
    try {
        $this->result->data = call_user_func($this->getCallable($function));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->result->err = ($e->getCode() > 0) ? $e->getCode() : -1;
        $this->result->message = $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $this->render();
}
```

}

Comment: I hope this is the solution but the "`Str::contains($callback, 'SerializableClosure')`" return an error : "`strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`"

Comment: I think I missed library. Please check again. I have been problem like you before and this way was help me.

Comment: Try var_dump variable $callback function after buildCallable.

Comment: I try it and it's doing nothing. The function `buildCallable` is never called. I think it's because `store(CreateCollectionRequest $request)` is never called too.

Comment: If the function `buildCallable` never call why you got error `strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100276/discussion-between-crunchy-artie-and-vanhonit).

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: The chat is disabled I can't return in it for read our discussion. You can find the code here : [link](https://gitlab.com/CrunchyArtie/crunchytheque)